# Store complex key (tuple) into JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, tuples, complextype

I'd like to store an object with a complex key (tuple) in JSON, for example:

```
obj = {('a', '1', '', 'b') : '1'}
```

But using:

```
import json
json.dumps(obj)
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

What is the fastest/best way to convert it to JSON and unpickle it later?

Note that it has to be stored in a typical JSON database (e.g. Cloudant/CouchDB/ElasticSearch).

Furthermore, I think that it is very practical to use the tuple in my program, and would thus prefer to end up with a dict containing tuples as keys (after loading the JSON).

Comment: Either turn the tuple into a string represenatation, or turn the dict into a list of tuples.

Comment: @tobias_k `tuple(str(('a', '1', '', 'b')))` leaves a mess btw (every char separated)

Comment: Use `repr` (not `str`) to convert to string and `ast.literal_eval` to convert back. `ast.literal_eval(repr(('a', '1', '', 'b'))) == ('a', '1', '', 'b')` is `True`.

Comment: But then (in the general case) how do you know which keys should be decided to tuples and which are literal strings like "(1, 2)"?

Comment: @DanD. Why `repr` and not `str`?

Comment: @TomDalton In this case, everything will be tuples (luckily)

Comment: From the doc on `str`: "The difference with `repr(object)` is that `str(object)` does not always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to `eval()`; its goal is to return a printable string." This means that if you intend the value to be acceptable to `eval` or better `ast.literal_eval` you must use `repr` and not `str`.

Comment: Consider that `ast.literal_eval(repr("1"))` produces `"1"` but `ast.literal_eval(str("1"))` produces `1`.

Comment: @DanD. Agreed that `repr` should be used, but in case of tuples, both `repr` and `str` produce the same output.

Comment: You could write a custom JSON encoder/decoder; I promise it's not that hard :). https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two workarounds that you can use.

1. Store the data as a list of tuples, instead of a dictionary. Note that you will have to turn the unhashable lists back into tuples when recreating the dictionary.

   ```
   >>> json.dumps(obj.items())
   '[[["a", "1", "", "b"], "1"]]'
   >>> {tuple(x): y for x, y in json.loads(_)}
   {(u'a', u'1', u'', u'b'): u'1'}
   ```
2. Convert the tuples into strings, and then parse those strings back to tuples when retrieving the values.

   ```
   >>> import ast
   >>> json.dumps({repr(x): y for x, y in obj.items()})
   '{"(\'a\', \'1\', \'\', \'b\')": "1"}'
   >>> {ast.literal_eval(x): y for x, y in json.loads(_).items()}
   {('a', '1', '', 'b'): u'1'}
   ```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't understand the first example really without the code.